# Get items from HTML Local Storage into HTML Table

Tags: javascript

This is the JavaScript code for my register page, and it stores the user data in the HTML local storage.

```
function storeUserDetail(){
    var titleSelected = document.getElementById("titleInput").value;
    var fNameInput = document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value;
    var lNameInput = document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value;
    var genderSelected = document.getElementById("genderInput").value;
    var uNameInput = document.getElementById("userNameInput").value;
    var pWordInput = document.getElementById("passWordInput").value;
    if(fNameInput === ""){
        document.getElementById("regMessage").innerHTML = "<span 
        class='error'>Please enter your First Name.</span>";
    }
    else if(lNameInput === ""){
        document.getElementById("regMessage").innerHTML = "<span 
        class='error'>Please enter your Last Name.</span>";   
    }
    else if(uNameInput === ""){
        document.getElementById("regMessage").innerHTML = "<span 
        class='error'>Please enter your Username.</span>";   
    }
    else if(pWordInput === ""){
        document.getElementById("regMessage").innerHTML = "<span 
        class='error'>Please enter your Password.</span>";   
    }
    else {
        var storeDetails = {};
        storeDetails.FirstName = document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value;
        storeDetails.LastName = document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value;
        storeDetails.Username = document.getElementById("userNameInput").value;
        storeDetails.Password = document.getElementById("passWordInput").value;
        document.getElementById("regMessage").innerHTML = "";
        localStorage[storeDetails.Username] = JSON.stringify(storeDetails);
```

How would I get the items from the local storage so I can store the users first name and last name into my HTML table? And for some reason it doesn't work when I use:

```
var storeDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage[Username]);
var table = document.getElementById("rankTable");
var row = table.insertRow();
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = storeDetails.FirstName
cell2.innerHTML = storeDetails.LastName;
```

My table is stored on a different page, probably this is the reason to why the code above doesn't work. Here is my HTML table:

```
<table id="rankTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You put items as `storeDetails.Username` but try to get it as `Username`. Try to use `storeDetails.Username` for retrieving data too. Or use constant value for that

Comment: Can you give an example in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing it as the username that came from the input element. So you'll need to get that username in order to retrieve it.

```
var Username = // ???
localStorage[Username]
```

So the question marks in the above code need to represent some way that you obtain that user name. A few ways would be:

- Store it in a cookie, and retrieve it from there
- Store it separately in local storage, assuming there's only one username to store per client machine.
- Ask for the username of the user. This will require that they provide it every time they visit.

Comment: `var storeDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage[Username]);` Can't I just change this code

Comment: On the console, it says the Username is undefined.

Comment: @Muddy: No, `Username` is the "key" you need to retrieve the data, but the user's name is stored *in* the data. That's like saying you can use your key to unlock your house when your keys are locked inside the house. You need the key to get in to the rest of the data. So unless you have the username, you can't get to the data. So you need to store it somewhere or ask the user for it.

Comment: What if I change the key?

Comment: @Muddy: Not sure what you mean. The `localStorange` is a storage that associates a key with a value. So if the data for the user `"Muddy"` is stored using the key `"Muddy"`, then that same key would need to be used to retrieve that data.

Comment: So how would I write the code to retrieve the data from my local storage?

Comment: @Muddy: I don't know. It depends on what you're doing. Do you simply want a user to be able to return to the browser and have the page retrieve the data automatically? Is there data for multiple users to be stored? If so, then how do you know which user is present? These are all things to consider before you pursue a solution. There is much information online regarding these problems.

Comment: I've been working on this part for the past two weeks, and I can't retrieve multiple users on my table.

Comment: So you want to store data for multiple users. And so again, how do you know which user's data should be retrieved? Who is sitting down at the computer, and how will you associate them with a user name?

Comment: I need a good example in code. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: A good example of what? Those are just questions you need to answer for yourself before you find a solution.